# Maven not running my tests

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a maven web app that uses spring framework with junit 5 and mockito for testing. I put two test classes in a src/test/java folder and named the with TestUT1 (has a simple unit test) and TestIT that uses mockitoextension to run a DAO integration test. running the test classes in eclipse by right clicking on them and run as junit test works and produces the right result. however, maven clean then install or test runs 0 Tests. I can't find out why?

Here is the properties and build setions in my POM that configures junit 5 and maven surefire plugin :

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <service-layer-version>1.0</service-layer-version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.16.Final</hibernate.version>
        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.21.0</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <junit-platform.version>1.1.0</junit-platform.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.1.0</junit-jupiter.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>process</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase><!-- this is actually the default, could  be omitted -->
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/metamodel</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                            <include>**/Test*.kt</include>
                            <include>**/Tests*.java</include>
                            <include>**/Tests*.kt</include>
                        </includes>
                        <properties>
                            <includeTags>junit5</includeTags>
                            <excludeTags>integration-test</excludeTags>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Comment: There were issue with JUnit Jupiter 5.0.1 and Surefire >= 2.20.0, I'm not sure if these have been resolved in JUnit Jupiter 5.1.0. Could you downgrade maven-surefire-plugin from 2.21.0 to 2.19.1 and retry?

Comment: I downgraded and now it now skips the testing (the console doesn't show Tests: Run: 0 ... etc